# global.asax code working fine in local but not after deploying on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

I have below code in global.asax. I am getting remote_addr details in my local but not after deployment.

log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["username"] = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.ToString();

Comment: Which part are failed on your side?Get remote_addr variable? or failed to get server variables?  What event did you registered the code? Did you see any exception in event viewer application log? Have you tried to capture first chance exception?  Have you installed asp.net module or change application pool identity?Provide more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Host Name, you need to turn the reverse dns lookup on. It is a behavioral change in IIS.
system.webServer/security/ipSecurity@doReverseDns and get the REMOTE_HOST server variable.